# Looping through a 3D array to find the mean and standard deviation

Tags: arrays, matlab, octave, mean

Ok so I have an array <134x106x108>. What I'm trying to do is loop through this array and store the average/standard deviation into another array. So basically there will be 134 <106x108 doubles> that will be in this meanArray and sdArray.

```
 %dayv=<134x106x108>
 sdArray=zeros(1,106,108);
 meanArray=zeros(1,106,108);
for i=1:size(dayv,1)
    %store means/standard deviation into an array
    meanArray(i,:,:) = squeeze(mean(dayv(i,:,:)));
    sdArray(i,:,:) = squeeze(std(dayv(i,:,:)));
end
```

Comment: So, you want each mean to be the mean value of the entire 106x108 values?

Comment: @jerad Yeah that's what I want. So it's an array of means but I'll have 134 of those.

Answer (score 4):

If you want each of your means to be the average of an entire 106x108 matrix then one easy solution is to reshape your 3d matrix into a 2d matrix using,

```
dayv2 = reshape(dayv,[134 106*108]);
```

Now each of those 106x108 matrices is a row vector in your new matrix.

Then

```
meanArray = mean(dayv2,2); % Get mean of each row
stdArray  = std(dayv2,0,2);% Std of each row
```

Answer (score 3):

You should not need to use a loop to solve this problem. The matlab built-in functions `mean` and `std` are capable of computing along individual dimensions of a matrix:

```
meanArray = squeeze(mean(dayv, 1));
sdArray = squeeze(std(dayv, [], 1));
```

The above code will average along the first dimension, and produce a `meanArray` and `sdArray` which are 106x108, as you initialize in your code. If, on the other hand, you want `meanArray` and `sdArray` to be single-dimensional vectors of length 134 (as implied by your loop), you would do

```
meanArray = mean( mean(dayv, 3), 2 );
sdArray = squeeze(std( reshape( dayv,  134, [] ), [], 2 ));
```

where `reshape` reorganizes your matrix so that it is 134x(106*108), so that `std` can act on it properly.

You can compare the above approach with the for-loop based code:

```
for i=1:size(dayv,1)
  slice = squeeze(dayv(i,:,:));
  meanArray(i) = mean(slice(:));
  sdArray(i) = std(slice(:));
end
```

Comment: So how do I get 134 mean values? If I just do `av=squeeze(mean(dayv,1));` it returns a <106x108>.