# MATLAB: How to output 2D array of the MEAN and SD of several 2D arrays calculating across each coordinate value?

Tags: arrays, matlab, grouping

This question is in reference to a posting from the following link:

[Looping through a 3D array to find the mean and standard deviation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13613557/looping-through-a-3d-array-to-find-the-mean-and-standard-deviation)

It seems that the first two commands: 1. meanArray = squeeze(mean(dayv, 1));
and 2. sdArray = squeeze(std(dayv, [], 1));) produce output arrays that reflect the given function applied at each dimension column by column.

I am wondering how it may be possible to generate an output array that computes the mean and standard deviation at each vertex (as in the row,column value) of either a 3d stack or of multiple 2d matrices.

For example, if I had the following values for three different control subjects, how could I generate a matrix that represents the standard deviation array (produce below) calculated at each vertex?

CTRL1
3   4   2
3   2   2
6   2   2

CTRL2
1   5   7
4   2   2
5   6   6

CTRL3
1   8   2
3   3   3
8   6   2

CTRL_OUTPUT_Array_SD

1.1547005384    2.0816659995    2.8867513459
0.5773502692    0.5773502692    0.5773502692
1.5275252317    2.3094010768    2.3094010768

I am new to MATLAB and to the syntax, so I do apologies if I misuse any terms within my description.

Thank you for the help!

Jacob

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you want is this:

```
CTRL1 = [3 4 2 3 2 2 6 2 2]; %// data, in the form of row vectors
CTRL2 = [1 5 7 4 2 2 5 6 6];
CTRL3 = [1 8 2 3 3 3 8 6 2];
CTRL = [ CTRL1; CTRL2; CTRL3 ]; %// concat rows to form a matrix
result = std(CTRL, 0, 1); %// std of each column, using "N-1" normalization
```

You may want to use `format long` to see all decimal digits.